# Free programs suggestions to simulate parabolic EDPs

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, parabolic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I'm interested in learning how to computationally simulate the behavior of parabolic partial differential equations, but I don't know where to start, what are the best free programs to use and where to find materials, books to study. I've heard of a program called FreeFem, but I still haven't found much about it, I even found some videos explaining how to use the program to model the weak solution of elliptical differential equations, using finite elements. But nothing about parabolic equations, using the semigroup formulation (I don't even know if it's possible to use such a formulation). Thanks for any suggestions.